# Does having your PC on for extended periods of time ie. 24 hours or so, effect your RAM?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

From what I have seen, this seems to be the case as my old ram had to be trashed and replaced but if it's otherwise I'd like to know.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited and eager to help you with your question but it's important to help them help you. Consider reading about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or some of the [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions) discussions about [how to ask a proper question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18588/329695). In this case, it's important to show what you've already researched by sharing a link, some quotes, and your thoughts. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)

Comment: One machine here has been running without pause 24/7 since 2008. All is still well.

Comment: Have many PC's that run 24/7 without effecting the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Your RAM might have failed for a lot of different reasons, but generally any properly designed system should be able to stay online 24/7 for 5-10 years at least. Fans, harddrives and PSUs are usually the only parts that "age" now that faulty motherboard capacitors have become uncommon.
Computers running for a decade or so without rebooting are not unheard of even if it's uncommon :)

However **dust, heat, moisture and mechanical wear** will shorten the life of any computer.

Tip: get [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and test your sticks individually before throwing them away next time. Good luck!